# Bluetooth missing in tray icons and Settings app in Juno?

Tags: release-juno, bluetooth

I just noticed that the Bluetooth icon is missing in the tray icons and the Settings app. How can I get it back?

Comment: Please execute this command in your terminal, sudo apt-get install switchboard-plug-bluetooth

Comment: It tells me that `switchboard-plug-bluetooth is already the newest version (2.1.2+r220~ubuntu5.0.1).`

Comment: Do you have `wingpanel-indicator-ayatana` installed? Does the *icon* missing only? (do you have bluetooth but no icon? If yes please log out and log in again if this resolve the issue)

Comment: 1. Yes I have that installed. 2. I said on my post that both the tray icon AND the Settings option went missing. Meaning, it's completely inaccessible for me. 3. I have logged out and restarted countless times

Comment: I don't have a blank icon forBluetooth, there's no "gap" between where it used to be. It's completely unavailable.

Comment: Can you try installing [blueman](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/x11/blueman) and see if that works.

Comment: I installed it but it throws an error and wouldn't open https://i.imgur.com/53swBQa.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

I totally ruled this out because I didn't think it would be at all related but when I turned off my WiFi (because I moved to a wired connection) it disabled Bluetooth along with it. I enabled WiFi again and restarted and Bluetooth is back.

Comment: oh,glad to know your problem is solved.